# Triple integral - how to find upper and lower bound

Tags: multiple-integral

I've got this integral.

$\int_RxyzdV$

on the domain

$R=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$ and $y\geq0$ and $z\geq 0\}$

I think I should convert it to spherical coordinates integration which I did, but then I don't know where I should integrate, I mean, the upper and lower bound. I've tried:

$0\leq\rho\leq 1$

$0\leq\phi\leq\pi/2$

$0\leq\theta\leq \pi/2$

But I'm not sure if its correct. Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: Draw your region, what is it?

Comment: puu.sh/yLWCO/7b93517df2.jpg I've uploaded a screenshot, but I'm not sure if its correct

Comment: You are almost correct, except that you required $x\ge 0$ as well with your limits. Can you see how to fix it? (Hint: Draw what's going on in the $xy$-plane and think polar coordinates.)

Comment: Well I've tried in GeoGebra, (I'm not the best by drawing these problems) but this is my try, when $y \leq 0$ and $z \leq 0$ I can see that the first quadrant is the area. https://puu.sh/yLWO0/75eec78168.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You have accounted for half of the volume you want.

Revisit your angular bounds. To cover all angles, one angular measure goes from $0$ to $2\pi$ (or $-\pi$ to $\pi$) and the other goes from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.

By limiting to $+y$ and $+z$ you'd be covering a quarter of all angles. Right now you're covering an eighth of all angles.

Spoiler answer:

> $-\pi/2 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$

Comment: So it should look like this? http://puu.sh/yLWY7/fe727c1960.jpg

I'm new to this btw.

Comment: It should look more like an orange wedge than half a grapefruit.

Comment: Yea, this is what I did before: https://puu.sh/yLWCO/7b93517df2.jpg but I believe I should "cut" it such that I've get a wedge. Now I understand what the other guy told me, but how shall I do that?

Comment: If I let $y=z$ then I get the wedge. http://puu.sh/yLXdX/82cfca3ab4.jpg

Comment: How are $\theta$ and $\phi$ defined? If $\theta$ is the angle relative to the $xy$ plane ("elevation") and $\phi$ is "azimuth" going around the $z$ axis, then your bounds for $\phi$ are wrong.

Comment: The first "wedge" was closer (I was thinking a quarter of an orange, not an eighth). This last one with $y=z$ isn't right.

Comment: I see. My first idea was the quarter (without $y=z$.) I don't know how it's defined. My problem is given at the very first. My $\theta$ and $\phi$ is something I found by my self.

My problem from the paper: https://puu.sh/yLXpV/0bc518d08e.png

Comment: Look at this picture (the $\phi$ is written $\varphi$) https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/Kugelkoord-def.svg/500px-Kugelkoord-def.svg.png

Comment: I can see that $\rho$ is from $0$ to $1$. and I believe that the $\theta$ is from $0$ to $\pi/2$ but my $\phi$ I don't know really. I see it starts from $x-$axis and yea. Sorry I'm lost.

Comment: Edited my answer if you completely give up ... Happy Holidays

Comment: Thank you. Happy holidays to you. - But actually I tried that too (your spoiler) but then my answer will be 0.

In Maple: https://puu.sh/yLY8V/4d25215175.png (x*y*z) is converted to spherical coordinates.

Comment: It should be zero! Your function is odd in each of the variables. Every place you have a point with $+x$, there's a corresponding point with $-x$ that cancels it out.

Comment: So you are saying that the result is zero, which I've got a lot of times?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. :)

Comment: Thank you man. Happy holiday to you again